# Problem with loading models with different shaders

Tags: opengl, model-loader

I am lerning opengl programming from http: //learnopengl.com .And i can load any model which i want.But if i want to load two models with different shaders,a problem occurs.
For example:
First i draw two models with same shader and there is no problem.

```
Model1.Draw(shader);
Model2.Draw(shader);
```

Then if i do this:

```
Model1.Draw(shader);
Model2.Draw(otherShader);
```

The first model is not drown.Only the second model is drown.
Here is my Model.h code and Mesh.h code:

Model.h: [Model.h](http://pastebin.com/DBgHpjAT)

Mesh.h [Mesh.h](http://pastebin.com/145jYBDW)

And if you want, these are my vertex and fragment shaders:

Shaders: http: //pastebin.com/d0v3Y4vU

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in the following code block is unnecessary:

```
glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( shader.getProgram(), ("material." + name + number ).c_str( ) ), i );
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + i );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->textures[i].id );
```

So remove it, and change the following GLSL code:

```
struct Material
{
    sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
    sampler2D texture_specular1;
    float shininess;
};
```

To:

```
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
uniform sampler2D texture_specular1;
```

Texture samplers must be defined as a uniform. Though I've never attempted that sort of GLSL code before, I'm surprised it even compiles.

You are confusing concepts here. Typically a non texture material would look like this:

```
struct Material
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
};
```

So, if using a mix of textures and values:

```
uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
uniform sampler2D texture_specular1;
uniform float shininess;
```

Then bind the two textures, and the uniform for shininess separately.
Keep your code simple, it really is the best way.